# SQL DB only holding one row?

Tags: java, android, sql

New to using databases, so not sure where my error lies to be honest.  Here is my code:

Creating the database

```
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
    "create table job_details (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
    + "company text not null, advertised text, status text not null, position text not null, " +
    "wage text, hours text, address text, " +
    "email text, number text, notes text);";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }
```

Creating a row

```
     public long createJob(String company, String advertised, String status, String position, String wage, String hours,
        String address, String email, String number, String notes) {

    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_COMPANY, company);
    initialValues.put(KEY_ADVERTISED, advertised);
    initialValues.put(KEY_STATUS, status);
    initialValues.put(KEY_POSITION, position);
    initialValues.put(KEY_WAGE, wage);
    initialValues.put(KEY_HOURS, hours);
    initialValues.put(KEY_ADDRESS, address);
    initialValues.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);
    initialValues.put(KEY_NUMBER, number);
    initialValues.put(KEY_NOTES, notes);

    return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}
```

Getting a cursor to all rows in table

```
     public Cursor fetchAllJobs() {

    return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_COMPANY,
            KEY_ADVERTISED, KEY_STATUS, KEY_POSITION, KEY_WAGE, KEY_HOURS,
            KEY_ADDRESS, KEY_EMAIL, KEY_NUMBER, KEY_NOTES}, null,
            null, null, null, null);
}
```

Using cursor to log some of the attributes of all the rows

```
    private void getAllData(){
    Cursor c = mDbHelper.fetchAllJobs();
    startManagingCursor(c);
    do{
        if(c.moveToFirst()){
            String company;
            String position;
            String number;

            int companyColumn = c.getColumnIndex(JobsDbAdapter.KEY_COMPANY);
            int positionColumn = c.getColumnIndex(JobsDbAdapter.KEY_POSITION);
            int numberColumn = c.getColumnIndex(JobsDbAdapter.KEY_NUMBER);

            do{
                company = c.getString(companyColumn);
                position = c.getString(positionColumn);
                number = c.getString(numberColumn); 
            }while(c.moveToNext());

            Log.d(TAG, "Company is = "+company);
            Log.d(TAG, "Position is = "+position);
            Log.d(TAG, "Number is = "+number);
        }
    }while(c.moveToNext());
}
```

When I use this code, the output/logged values are just those contained in the last row that I tried to enter in the database.  I am not sure if I am entering the data wrong, or looking up the database wrong.

Comment: If the SQL is confusing, consider encapsulating your DB access with an Active Record (http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) or Data Mapper (http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) type of approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
 do{
            company = c.getString(companyColumn);
            position = c.getString(positionColumn);
            number = c.getString(numberColumn); 
        }while(c.moveToNext());
```

When you want to read what a cursor is actually pointing to you don't need to move it. A cursor points to the full record.

Also your if statment always move the cursor back to the first result. That's probably why you were only seeing the first row. Try this instead.

```
private void getAllData(){
  Cursor c = mDbHelper.fetchAllJobs();
  startManagingCursor(c);

  while(c.moveToNext()){

        String company;
        String position;
        String number;

        int companyColumn = c.getColumnIndex(JobsDbAdapter.KEY_COMPANY);
        int positionColumn = c.getColumnIndex(JobsDbAdapter.KEY_POSITION);
        int numberColumn = c.getColumnIndex(JobsDbAdapter.KEY_NUMBER);


        company = c.getString(companyColumn);
        position = c.getString(positionColumn);
        number = c.getString(numberColumn); 


        Log.d(TAG, "Company is = "+company);
        Log.d(TAG, "Position is = "+position);
        Log.d(TAG, "Number is = "+number);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is better loop structure, though doesn't explain what was wrong with the original code.

Comment: Your right, I know why his loop is wrong, but I didn't go to the trouble of explaining why it's wrong. I should do that. I'll modify my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I see now that I was confused with what c.movetofirst() did. Was concentrating on the SQL parts of the code that I ignored my loops.

Answer (score 4):

Look at your loop.

```
do{
    if(c.moveToFirst()){
        String company;
        String position;
        String number;

        int companyColumn = c.getColumnIndex(JobsDbAdapter.KEY_COMPANY);
        int positionColumn = c.getColumnIndex(JobsDbAdapter.KEY_POSITION);
        int numberColumn = c.getColumnIndex(JobsDbAdapter.KEY_NUMBER);

        do{
            company = c.getString(companyColumn);
            position = c.getString(positionColumn);
            number = c.getString(numberColumn); 
        }while(c.moveToNext());

        Log.d(TAG, "Company is = "+company);
        Log.d(TAG, "Position is = "+position);
        Log.d(TAG, "Number is = "+number);
    }
}while(c.moveToNext());
```

You can think of a cursor as like turning the pages in a book. In this block:

```
do{
            company = c.getString(companyColumn);
            position = c.getString(positionColumn);
            number = c.getString(numberColumn); 
        }while(c.moveToNext());
```

You turned the page to the last one. So when you log, you're at the last one.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure if it was the most technically accurate, but I wanted a simple way to convey the concept. Glad it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the problem is in the database and not your loops?   I would try to connect to the database manually and do a SELECT on that table.  I think there is something funky that could be going on with your cursor and your loop that is making it not print all the rows.